# How can I stack two arrow images (upvote/downvote) on top of eachother using CSS?

Tags: css

[image][image]

uparrow.gif and downarrow.gif

So, it would look like so:
[image]
[image]

How can I create 3 divs and style them with CSS so those arrows are positions with the top arrow above the bottom arrow?

```
<div class="vote">  
<div class="uparrow" />  
<div class="downarrow" />  
</div>
```

Should I create a "vote" div with restricted width?  Would I float: top and float: bottom the two arrow divs with the background set as my two images?  I plan on having content directly to the right of the vote arrows so it needs to be restricted and tight.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use divs for an image - there's already a perfectly good img tag!

```
<div class="vote">
    <img alt="^" title="vote up"   src="/images/up.arrow.png" />
    <img alt="v" title="vote down" src="/images/down.arrow.png" />
</div>
```

And then simply:

```
.vote
{
    width: 15px;
    float: left; clear: left;
}

.vote img
{
    display: block;
    float: none; clear: both;
}
```

You may want to add some margin to the .vote to separate it from the content it will be next to.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `<div>` elements are `block-level` meaning they are one-per-line and will expand horizontally to fill their container.

Adding the click handling is another problem.  You could include the `<a>` and `<img>` elements in the `uparrow` and `downarrow` elements or you do it in CSS as you suggested (the less compatible way).  Another option is registering DOM events with Javascript.

HTML:

```
<div class="vote">  
<div class="uparrow" />  
<div class="downarrow" />  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.vote {
  width: 50px;
  float: left;
}

div.uparrow {
  background-image: url(...);
}

div.downarrow {
  background-image: url(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 divs. Float the text div left and put the two images in a single div.  use display: block on the images to force one below the other.

Answer (score 0):

A more semantic and efficient solution than divs would be this, which also takes care of positioning the vote box.

```
.content-item {padding-left:110px;position:relative; width:500px;border:1px solid red;}
.vote{width:100px;position:absolute; top:0; left:0;border:1px solid red;}
.vote h4 {style heading how you like}
.vote img{width:100px;height:30px;background:black;}

<div class="content-item"> content 
    <div class="vote">
    <h4>Vote</h4> 
    <img alt="vote up" src="..." />
    <img alt="vote down" src="..." />
    </div>
</div>
```